# How to input japanese text to Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to input japanese with the Ubuntu Japanese Keyboard (Mozc) into VSCode, however only the occidental letters appear and the dictionnary popup letting me choose which kanji to use for the hiragana inputed doesn't appear. VSCode is up to date, and I can easily input japanese characters with any other software.

Any idea how to fix that ?
Thanks

Comment: Experiencing the same issue, did you figure it out somehow?